# Scale the x- and y-axes of a plot of {x,y,z} to extend from 0 to 1

Tags: plotting

I have a two-dimensional (100 x 100) matrix of real values z $\in$ [0,1]. I'm interested in displying these values in a three-dimensional plot of {x,y,z} in which the x- and y-axes themselves range from 0 to 1.

Obviously, a very basic/elementary question, but I don't quite see how to get the x- and y-axes scaled as desired.

Are some options for ListPlot3D available for such a purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `DataRange`:

```
vals = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
ListPlot3D[vals, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}]
```

[image]

Comment: OK, thanks. Now vals = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {100, 100}];
ListPlot3D[vals, DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", "z"}] gives me the form of plot I desire.